# Python Multiprocessing: Children sending variable back to parent

Tags: python, variables, multiprocessing, parent

I have a pool that runs a function on a list of IPs and returns an integer (0 through 99). The number of children is determined by the number of IPs. The idea is the parent builds a dict with IP keys and the integers values.

I need the children to report the number back to the parent process so it can save it in a pickled file. Assigning the integer variable as global has not worked.

Reading a pickled file in as a dict:

```
infile = open(server_file, 'rb')
servers = pickle.load(infile)
infile.close()
```

Result:

```
servers = {'10.116.35.141': ''}
```

The function:

```
def check(server):
    response = urllib2.urlopen("http://"+server+"/avicapture.html")
    tall = response.read() # puts the data into a string
    html = tall.rstrip()
    match = re.search('.*In Progress \((.*)%\).*', html)
    if match:
        global temp
        global results
        temp = match.group(1)
        results = temp
        servers[server] = temp  # not setting key to temp in parent process like I want.
```

The pool:

```
p = Pool(len(servers))
p.map(check, servers)
p.close()
p.join()
```

My desired result in the parent process:

```
servers = {'10.116.35.141': 'integer from child'}
```

---

dano:

It is working now. Sort of. Here's the current state:

Starting with a dict of:

```
servers = { '10.116.35.141': '' }

def check(server):
    response = urllib2.urlopen("http://"+server+"/avicapture.html")
    tall = response.read() # puts the data into a string
    html = tall.rstrip()
    match = re.search('.*In Progress \((.*)%\).*', html)
    global temp
    if match:
        global temp
        global results
        temp = match.group(1)
        results = temp
        servers[server] = temp
        print servers
    return str(temp)
    print("Results: " +results)
```

Here is the pooling:

```
            if __name__ == "__main__":
                print "Print Servers:\n"+str(servers)
                print "Starting pool"
                p = Pool(len(servers))
                print "p.map(check, servers)"
                results = p.map(check, servers)
                p.close()
                p.join()
            d = dict(ent for ent in zip(servers, results))
            print "d = dict(ent for ent in zip(servers, results))\nResults in.."
            print(d)
            servers = d
            print "Translation into servers dict:"
            print(servers)
```

This results in the desired:

```
Print Servers:
{'10.116.35.141': ''}
Starting pool
p.map(check, servers)
{'10.116.35.141': '96'}
Server: 10.116.35.141 ... 96% 
d = dict(ent for ent in zip(servers, results))
Results in..
{'10.116.35.141': '96'}
Translation into servers dict:
{'10.116.35.141': '96'}
```

The problem starts when I have a dict with more than one key. For instance:

```
servers = { '10.116.35.141': '', '10.116.35.1': '' }
```

The way the additional keys are added is:

```
        input = raw_input("Add IP: ")
        if input in servers:
            print "Server already in servers list."
        elif input == "":
            print "No input."
        else:
            global servers
            servers[input] = ""
```

I get StringIO errors:

```
Print Servers:
{'192.168.91.236': '', '10.116.35.141': ''}
Starting pool
p.map(check, servers)
Process PoolWorker-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 232, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 88, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 71, in worker
    put((job, i, result))
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 366, in put
    return send(obj)
PicklingError: Can't pickle <type 'cStringIO.StringO'>: attribute lookup cStringIO.StringO failed
{'192.168.91.236': '', '10.116.35.141': '1'}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./bsdae", line 233, in <module>
    results = p.map(check, servers)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 148, in map
    return self.map_async(func, iterable, chunksize).get()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 422, in get
    raise self._value
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'message' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: Can you share the code you have so far? It'll help us to give you the best solution for your use-case.

Comment: @dano yes, here it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pool.map` actually allows you to return the results directly:

```
def check(val):
    return val + 5

if __name__ == "__main__":
    servers = [1,3,4,5]
    p = Pool(len(servers))
    results = p.map(check, servers)
    p.close()
    p.join()
    print(results)
```

Output:

```
[6, 8, 9, 10]
```

You can make your `check` function `return` the result, and it will end up in a list returned by the `map` call.

So if you have:

```
servers = ['1.1.1.1', '2.2.2.2', '3.3.3.3']
results = p.map(check, servers)  # Let's say this returns [1,2,3]
```

You can get the dict you want like this:

```
d = dict(ent for ent in zip(servers, results))
print(d)
```

Output:

```
{'3.3.3.3': 3, '1.1.1.1': 1, '2.2.2.2': 2}
```

Comment: This points me in the right direction, but it isn't working yet.. See my original post for results.

Comment: @user3841384 I think that exception is being thrown in the `check` function. Wrap that whole thing in a `try`/`exception`, and print something if you enter the `except` branch to confirm. You'd be looking for a line where you do something like `some_string = "blah" + a_variable`, where `a_variable` is an `int`, not a `str`.

Comment: Updated the results a StringIO error now...please see above. You're a great help right now - I appreciate it.

Comment: I just realized in your original answer, you assumed servers was an array? When 'servers' started and stayed a dict. Is that part of what is wrong here?

Comment: @user3841384 I think servers being a `dict` just means only the keys are passed to the subprocess, which is fine. the `StringIO` error you pasted indicates that `check` is trying to `return` a `StringIO` object, which isn't able to be pickled so it can be sent back to the parent. Make sure you're always returning a `str` from `check`.

Comment: It is returning str(temp). I realized that results = p.map(check, iplist) is not returning [1,2,3]. It is returning the first key and it's value. i.e. {'1.1.1.1': '1' }.   ** This is assuming I only have one ip in the list. More than that causes the StringIO error despite return str(temp) at the end of check

Comment: @pythduc Are you sharing the complete contents of `check`? I'm trying to figure out where this is coming from: `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'message' referenced before assignment`. Do you have a variable called `message` somewhere?

Comment: @pythduc `map` will only return a list; you're misreading something if it looks like it's returning a dict.

Comment: Hey, thanks again. Turns out i was returning str(temp) on the wrong indention. Works like a charm now. Thanks!